# How do I redirect to a page after login only if user model fields contain certain values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, routes

I’m using Rails 4.2.5.  I have a user model that includes the following fields:

```
height_feet
height_inches
weight
```

I additionally have a method in my controller (./app/controllers/users_controller.rb) for dealing with editing these fields …

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find(session["user_id"])
    render 'edit'
  end
```

However, what I want is that if all of these fields are empty, when the user logs in, I would like the user to be re-directed to the page where they edit these fields.  I’m unsure how to set this up.  In my config/routes.rb file I have

```
  root 'pages#index'

  get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
```

because I use third party providers (e.g. Google, Facebook) for authentication.  Not sure what other changes I should make to accommodate what I want to do.

**Edit:** Included the code for the "./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb" file ...

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    begin
      @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      flash[:success] = "Welcome, #{@user.name}!"
    end

    redirect_to url_for(:controller => 'user_objects', :action => 'index')
  end

  def destroy
    if current_user
      session.delete(:user_id)
      flash[:success] = 'See you!'
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

application_controller.rb

```
after_filter :verify_user_fields

def verify_user_fields
  if current_user.present? && current_user.weight.blank? && current_user.height_feet.blank? && current_user.height_inches.blank?
    redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user)
  end
end
```

alternatively, if you have as sessions controller, you could say something like:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    if user.weight.blank? && user.height_feet.blank? && user.height_inches.blank?
       redirect_to edit_user_path(user)
    else
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed In!"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed Out!"
  end
end
```

with a sessions controller you also have the option of an after_create callback instead of putting the conditional in the create action.

Comment: What controller/method am I putting this in?

Comment: Several ways to handle, but I would put it in a method inside the application controller and then call the method via before_filter. I'll update my answer to demonstrate this better.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my quesiton because I neglected to mention that I would like the user to see the edit page immediately after they login and only if those fields are blank.  How do I wire up the routing to go to this page after login?

Comment: this should do it...after they log in, we're checking for the existence of those three fields...and then redirecting to the edit_user_path if any of them are blank...you should run `rake routes` to make sure you have the right path `edit_user_path` may or may not be it--but you can put whatever path you want there and that's where you'll go.

Comment: Gotcha.  I inserted that code in application_controller.rb but got the error, 'Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return"' on the line "redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user)".

Comment: do you have a sessions controller?

Comment: I do.  I have included that code as an edit to my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good opportunity to use Rails [strong parameters.](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

```
User Controller

def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])

 if @user.update(user_params)
  flash[:success] = "Your account was successfully updated!"
  redirect_to @user
 else
  flash[:error] = "There was an error updating your account."
  render :edit
 end
end

private

def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:height_feet, :height_inches, :weight)
end
```

Comment: I'm not connecting the dots.  What controller am I putting this in? The users controller?

Comment: Yep, it's in the User Controller. I've edited my answers to show the full method.

Comment: this doesn't actually address the issues raised in the question. doesn't check for the existence of those particular things and would only run on update, not sign-in.